# Class diagrams - do aggregated/composed classes automatically see each other?

Tags: object-oriented, uml, class-diagram

Let's say that in the game, a player has a pet:

Player<>------Pet

Obviously player can access Pet's fields and methods, but I assume Pet does not know about the player?
I need that Pet can access the player as well, how should I model that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UML, an aggregation relationship has a directionality, which can be

- uni-directional, where the `Player` knows about the `Pet`, but not the other way around. This is usually indicated with an arrow on the end of the line:

  Player <>------> Pet
- bidirectional, where both the `Player` and the `Pet` can access each other. This is usually indicated by the absence of an arrow (like you used in the question):

  Player <>------- Pet

In most programming languages, there is no real equivalent of the bidirectional relation, so it is usually emulated by using two uni-directional relations (pointers/references) and a bit of logic to ensure that if you follow both links, you end up back in the same object.

Comment: thank you, that very extremely helpful. Is there a way I could contact you? I look for someone to explain me these things (email) for some reasonable money

Comment: @user970696: I am sorry, but I don't do private consulting. Besides that, sometimes I am simply wrong and if I am wrong in email, there is nobody that could point it out.